# Gcov/Code coverage for Operating System

Tags: c++, linux, code-coverage, gcov, gcovr

I have a custom operating system(i.e. call it "CustomOS") which is based off off Fendora. It is identical to Fendora except it has a custom kernel and some special tools installed on it.

The custom OS image is compiled/built on a fendora machine (Machine A) and is loaded on to a different (Machine B)

I want to run basic Filesystem tests on the "CustomOS" (Machine B) and generate GCOV/Code coverage data for these tests.

Given that the operating system is complied on a different machine(Machine A) , Is it possible to generate Gcov/code coverage for Machine B ?

If so, could someone explain how I could go about doing this ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: you want to exploit on machine A the gcno generated on machine B, correct?

Comment: Yes  . I was under the impression that the gcno files will get generated on Machine A since that is where its complied . I believe the .gcna files will get generated on Machine B after running the test. I want sure how it work because the source code exists on Machine A , and the generated gcna files will be on Machine B

Comment: FYI, I did a similar thing while compiling the AOSP, thus I would say that there must be a way for you to do that, but I can hardly help you more without a setup as I did that quite a long time ago and I do not remember every steps (the only one I remember is making sure the versions of lcov match otherwise you get some cryptic error)